# Number of orbits of the natural action of order preserving bijections of $\mathbb Q$ on $\mathbb Q^n$

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, ordered-fields

By an order preserving map $f : \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q$, let us mean $ x > y \implies f(x) > f(y)$ . Let $Aut (\mathbb Q) =\{ f : \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Q : f $ is bijective and order preserving $\}$. Then $Aut (\mathbb Q)$ acts naturally on $\mathbb Q^n$ as $f . (a_1,...,a_n)=(f(a_1),...,f(a_n))$. Then is it true that the number of orbits under this action is finite ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is true. One way to prove it is to prove that two $n$-uples $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ and $(b_1,\dots,b_n)$ are in the same orbit if and only if they are arranged in the same order, i.e. if and only if $a_i < a_j\Leftrightarrow b_i< b_j$ and $a_i=a_j\Leftrightarrow b_i=b_j$. So the number of orbits will be equal to the number of possible orderings of your $n$ numbers. Such an ordering is completely described by the function that gives to every $a_i$ its rank, so the set of such ordering is in bijection with the set of functions $\{1,\cdots,n\}\to \{1,\cdots,n\}$ whose image is $\{1,\cdots, m\}$ for some $m$. In particular, there must be less than $n^n$ such orders.

It's pretty clear that two $n$-uples in the same orbit must have the same order; for the other direction, it is enough to prove that if $a_1<a_2<\cdots <a_m$ and $b_1<b_2<\cdots<b_m$ then there exist an order-preserving bijection $f:\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{Q}$ such that $f(a_i)=b_i$ for all $i$. But for that you can just take a piecewise-affine function between the points $(a_i,b_i)$ and $(a_{i+1},b_{i+1})$; since all the $a_i,b_i$ are rationals, every piece will be $\mathbb{Q}$-affine, and thus map rationals to rationals bijectively.

Comment: Your classification of when two points are in same orbit is very nice. So if we define an equivalence relation on $\mathbb Q^n$ by saying two $n$-tuples are equivalent iff they are arranged in the same order, then the no. of equivalence classes is exactly the no. of orbits for our action ... could you please elaborate on how to show that this no. of equivalence classes is finite ? ... btw to make it clearer ... I'm not asking whether every orbit is finite ... rather I'm asking that whether the no. of possible orbits is finite ...

Comment: @misao I've added an explanation.

Comment: By affine piece, do you mean $f(x)=b_i + (x-a _i)(b_{i+1}-b_i)/(a_{i+1} - a_i)$ for $a_i \le x \le a_{i+1}$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.